# SCSS modify parent selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Is there a way to add a class to the first element of a nested selector with .scss?
Imagine the example below:

```css
body p {
  color: black;
}

body.other-mode p {
  color: red;
}
```

Would it be possible to express it like this (or in a similar way, since this won't compile)

```
body p {
  & {
    color: black;
  }
  .other-mode& {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I'm aware this can be written like this, but that's just a different way of "solving" an example of the issue.

```css
body {
  & p {
    color: black;
  }
  
  &.other-mode p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I also tried using some scss selectors but they don't work quite as expected, in the case below the selectors ends up being `body p body.other-mode p` instead of `body p`

```
body p {
  & {
    color: black;
  }
  #{selector-replace(&, "body", "body.other-mode")} {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your last solution work, you can use [@at-root](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root).

```
body p {
  & {
    color: black;
  }
  @at-root #{selector-replace(&, "body", "body.other-mode")} {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

compiles to

```css
body p {
  color: black;
}
body.other-mode p {
  color: red;
}
```

---

But personally, I find your original solution the most readable.
`body { &.other-mode p {color: red;} }`
I find the split `body` and `p` more convenient in SCSS.

Comment: Thank you, that works, so `@at-root` just removes the `&` at the start?
FYI, this was a minimal example, otherwise I would agree with your simpler approach. (no point in posting long nested selectors here, not that I believe long selectors are good, but I was overriding the default behavior of an external style and the specificity had to be high enough)